# Calculating time complexity of recursive algorithm.

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I have just started solving Topcoder algorithm problems and have written this algorithm for SRM 466 Div 2 LotteryTicket problem in Java.

As I am not good with time complexity so if somebody could explain me how to calculate time complexity for this algorithm step by step.

```
public static String buy1(int price,int...b){
    int sum=0; String stat="IMPOSSIBLE";

    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
        sum=sum+b[i];

    if(sum==price)
        return "POSSIBLE";

    if(b.length>1){
        stat=buy1(price,Arrays.copyOfRange(b,0,b.length-1));
        stat=buy1(price,Arrays.copyOfRange(b,1,b.length));
    }

    return stat;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For your case , The recurrence relation is 
(let b.length() be bn)

```
                     ___________buy1(p,bn-1) (as (b,0,b.length-1) equivalent is bn-1 in number )
                    /
    buy1(p,bn) ____/
                   \
                    \___________ buy1(p,bn-1)  (as (b,1,b.length) equivalent is bn-1 in number )
```

So our problem for n = two sub-problem of n-1 hence our time function T(n) is as follows

```
   T(n)=2T(n-1)+c (For convenience lets eliminate c as it is very less compared to T(n) for this instance )
   T(n)=2[2(T(n-2))]
   T(n)=2{2[2(T(n-3))]} ===> 2poweri(T(n-i))  -------- equation(1)
```

The recurrence ends when it meets base condition .  Lets say T(0)=c(be base condition)  that means t(n-i)=t(0) for base condition .so i=n

Substituting i value in  equation(1) we get 2power(n){t(0)}

So our Time function value  will be 2power(n) and our complexity of program is equal to bigoh(2power(n))

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **recursion tree method and master method** to find the complexity.

Check [this](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/lectures/lec20-master/lec20.html) out for more ideas on how to approach this problem.

As an additional exercise try computing the complexity of merge sort using this.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. Lets calcluate it correctly ;)
So we will check the worst situation when condition (sum == price) will never appear.

First let's check complecity when b.length = 1. Then you should use only only one "=" operation inside the cycle:

```
for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++)
```

And 2 inside initialization:

```
int sum=0; String stat="IMPOSSIBLE";
```

Next step. Lets calculate this task for N.
First you need to do N "=" operations inside first the cycle, 2 inside initialization and 2 operations inside if.

```
    stat=buy1(price,Arrays.copyOfRange(b,0,b.length-1));
    stat=buy1(price,Arrays.copyOfRange(b,1,b.length));
```

Another operations are made inside recursive step. So we can use recurrent formula for this situation, which equals:

f(n) = 4 + n + 2*f(n-1), f(1) = 3

Solution of this equation is:
f(n) = -6+5 * 2^n-n

So complecity of your algo is exponential. O(2^n)
I am ignoring all another operations, except "=" because they will not change asymptotic complexity.